# Using a string in command line input (python) to refer to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a few pre-defined dictionaries in my python code, *e.g.*:

```
Parameter_A = {'Alpha':0.31, 'Beta':0.69}
Parameter_B = {'Alpha':0.55, 'Beta':0.75}
```

During execution of the python script (*foo.py*) I refer to the chosen parameter dictionary that I want to use (*i.e.* Parameter_**A** or Parameter_**B**). Like:

```
python foo.py A
```

And in the python script I have:

```
var = sys.argv[1]
Param = 'Parameter_' + var
```

The line (in script)

```
print 'Param = ', Param
```

gives output:

```
Param = Parameter_A
```

But, when I try to access the elements in the dictionary using this method,

```
Param['Alpha']
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'Param' is not defined
```

I could see that in this method 'Param' (which has the string Parameter_A as its value) is of type 'str'.

But, I will really appreciate if someone can tell me how I can take 'A' or 'B' as a command line argument to indicate which one of the two dictionaries (Parameter_A or Parameter_B) my code should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval` - it's potentially dangerous (depending who supplies the arguments to your program)

you could look them up in `globals()`

But why not use a dict for Parameter?

```
Parameter = {'A': {'Alpha':0.31, 'Beta':0.69},
             'B': {'Alpha':0.55, 'Beta':0.75}}
Param = Parameter[sys.argv[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` bif.

```
import sys

Parameter_A = {'Alpha':0.31, 'Beta':0.69}
Parameter_B = {'Alpha':0.55, 'Beta':0.75}

var = sys.argv[1]
Param = 'Parameter_' + var

d = eval(Param)

print(d['Alpha'])
```

Terminal
`$ python foo.py A`
Output
`0.31`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Param = 'Parameter_' + var` will only create a string `Parameter_A` not value of `Parameter_A` is assigned or refered anyways, on reading your code, to create something like that, you can use `globals` or `eval`.

**Using globals**

```
  var = sys.argv[1]
  Param = globals()['Parameter_' + var]  
  # here you are refering `Prameter_A` as `Param`
  print 'Param = ', Param  
  print 'Param[Alpha] = ', Param['Alpha']
```

**Using eval**

```
  var = sys.argv[1]
  # eval excecutes the string as python code
  # so if var is `A;import os;os.remove('somefile')`
  # will remove the file
  Param = eval('Parameter_' + var)  
  # here you are refering `Prameter_A` as `Param`
  print 'Param = ', Param  
  print 'Param[Alpha] = ', Param['Alpha']
```